# Trim result is unexpected?

Tags: php, trim

```
$individual_file["uri"] = "public://iStock_000000527255XSmall.jpg";
print_r(ltrim($individual_file["uri"], "public://"));

Result -: Stock_000000527255XSmall.jpg
```

Why the missing i? But when my character starts with si, I get si in the result. Why does trim behave differently?

```
$individual_file["uri"] = "public://siStock_000000527255XSmall.jpg";
print_r(ltrim($individual_file["uri"], "public://"));

Result -: siStock_000000527255XSmall.jpg
```

Comment: any special reason you want to use `ltrim` ? if not `str_replace` will work

Comment: @zzlalani - The question is not how to do it, explode, and str_replace will work, why doesn't trim?

Comment: you are right. my bad

Comment: @zzlalani - It's perfectly fine. I am pretty sure I will end up using str_replace anyways. Cheers :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because *charlist* is literally a list of single characters to remove from the left side of the string and *i* is listed in *public://*. Any character that falls in this list will be removed, no matter the order.

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php

In fact this:

```
$individual_file["uri"] = "public://iStock_000000527255XSmall.jpg";
print_r(ltrim($individual_file["uri"], "publc://"));
```

would output:

```
ic://iStock_000000527255XSmall.jpg
```

Another example by changing the order:

```
$individual_file["uri"] = "public://iStock_000000527255XSmall.jpg";
print_r(ltrim($individual_file["uri"], "bcilpu:/"));
```

would output:

```
Stock_000000527255XSmall.jpg
```

Comment: That's how trim worked....Feck me! I had no idea, cheers!